# Hook breakpoint in ida7.0 failed

Tags: python, dbg

I try to hook breakpoint at 0x403E65 in ida7.0, but unfortunately, it nevers reach the method `DbgHook.dbg_bpt`, so my hook is useless. Refer to this [demo](https://gist.github.com/nkaretnikov/923da6534c3326bd2249e554a007216d), I really don't understand what's wrong.

> ida_script.py.

```
from idaapi import *

chunks = {}

class DbgHook(DBG_Hooks):
    def dbg_bpt(self, tid, ea):
        global chunks
        print "test"
        chunks[GetRegValue("eax")] = GetRegValue("ebx")
        continue_process()
        return 0

try:
    if debugger:
        debugger.unhook()
except Exception as e:
    pass


AddBpt(0x403E65)
debugger = DBG_Hooks()
debugger.hook()
request_start_process("C:\\Users\\win7\\Desktop\\codemap.exe", "", "")
run_requests()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an existing breakpoint which is disabled, you'll need to enable it.